# MySQL/InnoDB - Circular foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, key, constraints

{Totally different question than the one I asked an hour ago}

Using MySQL, moving from MyISAM to InnoDB tables.  Database design started with dumping the data and re-importing it without foreign keys or constraints. Adding those one at a time to find errors.

What's the correct way to handle having `ParentTable` and `ChildTable`, where there is both a one-to-many relationship from `ParentTable` to `ChildTable`, and a one-to-one relationship from `ParentTable` to `ChildTable`?

This can occur when a `ParentTable` has many `ChildTable` choices, and has either a currently selected `ChildTable` choice.

My situation is where there are multiple photographs of something, and I want to have a record of all of those, along with the one I feel is best.  (Resolution, clarity, color accuracy.)  For my situation, there conceptually isn't a `ParentTable` until there's a `ChildTable`, and visa-versa.

In my current MyISAM design, `ParentTable` has `IDChildTable` to create the one-to-one relationship of the best choice, and `ChildTable` has `IDParentTable` to create the one-to-many relationship of all the available choices.  Upon the first creation, a `ParentTable` is created then a `ChildTable`, then `ParentTable` is updated with the `IDChildTable`.

If I add foreign key constraints, I can't create new records simultaneously.

All I can think of is:

- Not have constraints in this situation
- Remove the one-to-one relationship, and have a `Best` boolean in `ChildTable` which introduces the undesired possibilities of there being zero or multiple `Best` choices among multiple `ChildTable` entries for a single `ParentTable`
- I could allow one or both of the foreign key ID's to be null.  Right now they're not null.  Don't love this idea because I'd only want null's to be valid for the fractions of a second between the two inserts.
- Wait for MySQL/InnoDB to allow deferring foreign key constraint checks in a transaction until commit.  MySQL 5.6 doesn't support this, don't know if there's plans to.
- Before the two inserts, disable foreign key checks.  Don't like this, because there shouldn't be the illusion of consistency with it periodically being bypassed.  Granted, this at least keeps updates consistent.

Don't love any of these choices.  Thoughts?

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE `ParentTable` (
  `IDParentTable` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `IDChildTableBest` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDParentTable`),
  KEY `ParentTable_IDChildTableBest` (`IDChildTableBest`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
---Would like to also have, but can't do both of these---
CONSTRAINT `ParentTable_IDChildTableBest` FOREIGN KEY (`IDChildTableBest`) REFERENCES `ChildTable` (`IDChildTable`)

CREATE TABLE `ChildTable` (
  `IDChildTable` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `IDParentTable` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDChildTable`),
  KEY `ChildTable_IDParentTable` (`IDParentTable`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
---Would also like to have, but can't do both of these---
CONSTRAINT `ChildTable_IDParentTable` FOREIGN KEY (`IDParentTable`) REFERENCES `ParentTable` (`IDParentTable`)
```

**ParentTable**

```
IDParentTable   IDChildTableBest
            1                  4
```

**ChildTable**

```
IDChildTable    IDParentTable
           1                1
           2                1
           3                1
           4                1
           5                1
```

As a simple example... ParentTable could describe physical objects.  ParentTable(1) could be for a particular chair.  ChildTable could hold or be links to photographs.  ChildTable(1)-(5) could be different photographs of the chair represented by ParentTable(1), perhaps with different cameras, lighting, backgrounds, etc.

ParentTable(1) has a one-to-one relationship with ChildTable(4), signifying that photograph 4 is the chosen "best one" right now.  The user could change their mind, or add future photographs that may or may not take the "best of" title.

ParentTable(1) also has a one-to-many relationship with ChildTable(1)-(5), which are all the photographs available to choose from.

Comment: A long winded question. Can you provide your current table schema in a proper form (`DESC table_name` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`) and relevant sample data to illustrate your question.

Comment: Sure, see below.  (Was too long to post as comment.)